# Is there any way to extract a particular part of string from column value in mysql or java?

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I want to show only some part of string from column values before first appearing of price.

eg :

> BOM 9W BDQ 3285 9W BOM 3285 INR6570END XT 380WO113
>
> AMD EK X/DXB EK MUC 1241.36CWE1SIN1/LNE3 EK X/DXB
>
> BDQ 9W MAA 6300 INR6300END

Output :

> BDQ
>
> MUC
>
> MAA

Comment: How do you determine which part is wanted?

Comment: before 1st price appearing. price is determined by minimum 4 continuous numeric value

Comment: Doing this in MySQL is tedious.

Comment: Do such stuff _before_ inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the days are getting longer again...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,string VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO my_table (string) VALUES
('BOM 9W BDQ 3285 9W BOM 3285 INR6570END XT 380WO113'),
('AMD EK X/DXB EK MUC 1241.36CWE1SIN1/LNE3 EK X/DXB'),
('BDQ 9W MAA 6300 INR6300END');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ints;

CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

SELECT b.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,' ',i+1),' ',-1) x, MIN(i) rank FROM my_table JOIN ints GROUP BY id,x ORDER BY id,rank 
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,' ',i+1),' ',-1) x, MIN(i) rank FROM my_table JOIN ints GROUP BY id,x ORDER BY id,rank 
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND b.rank = a.rank -1
 WHERE a.x REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}';

+----+-----+------+
| id | x   | rank |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 | BDQ |    2 |
|  2 | MUC |    4 |
|  3 | MAA |    2 |
+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: im getting Error Code: 1146. Table 'db.ints' doesn't exist

Comment: @MaDHaNMinHo Oh yeah - I forgot that bit. This query relies on a table of integers (0-9). I'll edit... and edited

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first price, not all, you should try something like:

```
^.*?(\w+?)\s\d+(\s|\.)
```

and take the match for the first group, the one defined by `(\w+?)`.

For delimiting the price I used `(\s|\.)` because as I can see on second line it can contains a dot, is it true?

If you want to test it use [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jC4iU1/1).

Comment: how to do this in mysql query? yes it can also have dot in some cases :(

Comment: Sorry I focused on RegEx but I don't know how to use it in MySQL. :(
I hope someone else can help you!

Comment: @MaDHaNMinHo This is a preg_match - which MySQL doesn't support out-of-the-box. The simplest solution would to parse the data set through some application code which does support preg_match, like PHP

Comment: @Strawberry im using jsp. need to look for solution in java

Comment: @MaDHaNMinHo Yeah, you can build a java function I guess. I don't know java, but I know it (or something like it) has been done before.

Comment: @MaDHaNMinHo I'm not saying it can't be done via some other process in MySQL - it can - it's just a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using simple java code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Patrn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //input strings
        String eqn[] = { "BOM 9W BDQ 3285 9W BOM 3285 INR6570END XT 380WO113 " 
                 ," AMD EK X/DXB EK MUC 1241.36CWE1SIN1/LNE3 EK X/DXB " 
                 ," BDQ 9W MAA 6300 INR6300END " };
      //match 4 digit numbers
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d{4}+");
        for(int i=0;i<eqn.length;i++){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(eqn[i]);
      //finding first match 
        if (m.find()) {
            //m.start() used to find start position of matched substring
            //print substring of original string from -4 position of matched 
          System.out.println(eqn[i].substring(m.start()-4,m.start()-1));
        }
       }
    }
}
```